# If two binary forms represent the same prime they must be equivalent

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The following exercise appears on the book "Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2$":
[image]

the lemma 2.3 mentioned on the hint is this:
[image]

I tried examining the middle coefficient $B$, but if $p = f(p_0, q_0) = g(p_1, q_1)$ none of the variables in $B$ is the same for the equivalent forms of $f$ and $g$ given by the lemma. So i have no idea about how to solve the item (a).

Comment: I recommend adding some other books for this material. I put an answer; you would find this material, with illustrative exercises, in L. E. Dickson, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, published about 1929. It has been republished frequently, an inexpensive used copy ought to be available. Indeed, many number theory books treat Gauss equivalence. My favorite is D. A. Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this sort of thing becomes clear if you practice reducing forms by hand; finding equivalence is a step by step process. The modular group, "proper" equivalence, happens when repeating two steps to manipulate the form in a useful way. I like to use the notation $$ \langle A,B,C \rangle  $$ to denote the form $$ f(x,y) = A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 . $$ The matrix ($t$ is some integer)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
leads to
$$ \langle A,B,C \rangle \mapsto \langle A,B + 2At,C +Bt +At^2 \rangle $$

The matrix 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
leads to
$$ \langle A,B,C \rangle \mapsto \langle C,-B ,A \rangle $$
Gauss reduction is the process of beginning with a form, alternating these two steps ( each time the value of $t$ is chosen to minimize $|B|,$ if we are discussing a positive form).

For your part a, you begin with two forms, which are properly equivalent to
$$  \langle p,B,C \rangle $$
for fixed prime $p.$ Just apply the first step for each, 
$$ \langle p,B,C \rangle \mapsto \langle p,B + 2pt,C +Bt +pt^2 \rangle $$
Since we can add or subtract $2p$ to the middle term, we can demand 
$$  -p < B \leq p $$
for both.  What about the discriminant? Naming $B_1, C_1, B_2, C_2,$ we reach
$$ \Delta = B_1^2 - 4 p C_1 = B_2^2 - 4 p C_2 $$
This tells us that
$$ B_1^2 \equiv B_2^2 \pmod p  $$
as well as $B_1 \equiv B_2 \pmod 2$

I think I will stick to odd $p$ for now. The result is just
$$ B_2 \equiv \pm B_1 \pmod p $$  But since we arranged
$$  -p < B_j \leq p $$  and $p$ is odd, we actually have
$$ B_2 = \pm B_1  $$ There is a detail that we cannot have one of them $p$ and the other $0,$ as $p$ is odd but $0$ is even. And then $ \Delta = B_1^2 - 4 p C_1 = B_2^2 - 4 p C_2 $ tells us that $C_1 = C_2$

everything else matches. When $B_2 = - B_1,$ we get improper equivalence with the  matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which leads to
$$ \langle A,B,C \rangle \mapsto \langle A,-B ,C  \rangle $$